# DatePicker en Vue.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, jquery-datepicker

Estoy utilizando Vue.js para hacer una aplicación, pero solo la estructura. O sea, para montar los formularios, plugins y demás, prefiero hacerlo con Javascript o en su defecto, con algo ya prediseñado con Jquery.

Es el caso de DatePicker, pero no me funciona. Cuando pincho sobre el formulario, no me salen las fechas, y no tengo ningún tipo de error en la consola.

En Vue.js, en el index.html he colocado los cdn a pelo para proceso de desarrollo:

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap- 
     daterangepicker/3.0.3/daterangepicker.min.css" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-daterangepicker/3.0.3/daterangepicker.min.css.map" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-daterangepicker/3.0.3/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-daterangepicker/3.0.3/moment.min.js"></script>



 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('.input-daterange').each(function() {
    $(this).datepicker('clearDates');
 });

 });
 </script>
```

Pero el input, está en un componente de Vue.

```
 <div class="input-group" style="margin-right: 20px">
        <input type="text" class="input-daterange form-control" name="dateFrom" id="dateFrom" value="">
        <span class="fa">a</span>
        <input type="text" class="input-daterange form-control" name="dateTo" id="dateTo" value="">
        </div>
```

Si el código Jquery me funciona, y Boostrap también, sin importarlo al componente previamente, ¿Que puede ser lo que haga que no me funciona?

Gracias!

Comment: Podrias ser mas especifico sobre donde estas importando cada cosa? no queda muy claro que estas haciendo, ni siquiera para que usas vue, si realmente no lo estas usando...

Comment: Estoy usando Vue para la estructura del programa, y para utilizar Vue-Router, aparte de cargar datos con Promises, etc. Pero lo que son los elementos, no quiero utilizar Vuecidity y cosas así, quiero hacerlo con Boostrap. Dicho esto, cargo los CDN en el index.html, e inicializo daterange en el mismo Index. Pero el input, lo tengo en un componente de Vue.

Comment: [bootstrap-vue](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/) no te sirve por algo en particular?

Comment: Entra en conflicto con postcss.

Comment: Y el DatePicker que quiero usar es este:
https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/markup.html#date-range

Comment: En general la función `$(document).ready(...)` se usa para prevenir asignarle handlers a los elementos antes de que estén en el DOM. En tu caso eso no basta. El DOM puede estar listo sin que componente que tiene el datepicker se haya rendereado. Para eso instancias el datepicker dentro del evento `mounted` de tu componente. Antes de gatillarse ese evento, el contenido del componente no existe.

Comment: Tienes razón amenadiel. Estoy probando pero aún así en el mounted no funciona, pero tiene que ser por algo de eso.

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar el contenido completo del componente?

Comment: Buenas, al final lo solucioné agregando un componente de VUE que no me entraba en conflicto con PostCss. Al final siempre es la mejor manera.